# VSCode Replace Variable Name Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

In MATLAB there is a really nice feature where when you change a variable name in a script it gives you the option to press *Shift* and *Enter* to replace all instances of that variable.

Is a keyboard shortcut/feature like this possible in VSCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a combination of shortcuts:

`CTRL + H -> ALT + W -> [Type New Name] -> Enter`

- Highlight the word/variable
- Hit CTRL + H (Find & Replace)
- Hit ALT + W (Match whole word)
- Type in the new name and press enter.

You can hit `ALT + C` to after `CTRL + W` if you'd like to match case too if the language is case sensitive.

[There's also great answers and alternative methods over on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346481/how-do-i-find-and-replace-all-occurrences-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I think it is Ctrl+Alt+Enter and not just Enter.